# Java - File -->ByteArray-->Blob and vice-versa

Tags: java

I am trying to convert file to byte array and then to Blob to store in database.

and then while retrieving from database I am converting Blob to byte array and then byte array to file
I am using JAVA1.6

Below is the code I am trying to use :-

```
// For converting file to bytearray and then to blob
byte[] img = new byte [(int) file.length()];

blob.setBytes(1L,img);

// For converting back to byte Array
Blob blob = rs.getBlob(file_contents);
byte[] blobAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1,(int)blob.length());
```

I debugged and found out that, the byte array is not the same in both the cases, because of which I am not able to open the image. Can anybody please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks 
SJ

Comment: Do you write anything to `img`? Looks like an array of `0`s here.

Comment: Show us the code you have for reading the file into the array. What you have now is just creating an array that has the same length as the file.

Comment: Put up a complete [mcve]